# Keep the first word after each comma in a string when there are multiple commas in the string

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

Hi I need to remove a word after a separation after each comma. For example, if the first index in a column is

```
'stack overflow, ask question , keep remove'
```

(note that they are all in one sting)

I need the output to be,

```
'stack, ask, keep'
```

(this is in one string)

so the first word is kept and the rest of words removed after each comma.
I used .split but I did not get the result.
Here is my approach,

```
 final_re= [mydf.mycolumn.str.split(' ')[index][0] for index in range(0, len(mydf))]
```

In this case, it keeps the first word that means if the input is

```
'stack overflow, ask question , keep remove'
```

my output would be just

```
'stack'
```

however, I need the out put to be

```
'stack, ask, keep'
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: assume ``text = "stack overflow, ask question , keep remove"``. Then run the list comprehension: ``[entry.split()[0] for entry in text.split(",")]`` It could be helpful if you shared a sample dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you required output

```
string = 'stack overflow, ask question , keep remove'
', '.join([i.split()[0] for i in string.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to remove the parts from a string `s` that you don't need:

```
import re
res = re.sub(r"(?: .*?)?(, |$)", r"\1", s)
```